# Loading FXML file from dependency

Tags: java, javafx

I need to load an fxml file from a dependency but I got an error...

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.38</version>
</dependency>
```

**project**

```
try {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(ClassLoader.getResource("com.mycompany.framework/userWindow.fxml"));

    UserController controller = new UserController();
    loader.setController(controller);

    Parent root = loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("Users");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    String exceptionMessage = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex);
    Log.error("Error loading user panel: " + exceptionMessage);
}
```

**Error:**

```
  java: non-static method getResource(java.lang.String) cannot be referenced from a static context
```

The "userWindow.fxml" file is located in the resources folder of the framework project. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: try `SomeClassFromYourDependency.class.getClassLoader().getResource("com/mycompany/framework/userWindow.fxml")` or `SomeClassFromTheSamePackageAsTheFXMLFile.class.getResource("userWindow.fxml")` assuming the FXML file is there

Comment: Are you trying to create a [custom node](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#fxmlloader)? If so, I think you are doing things incorrectly. Once you have added the dependency, you should be able to simply do something like `CustomControl customControl = new CustomControl();`.